# invalid Token on reset password with ASP.NET, when multiple instances running

Tags: c#, asp.net, kubernetes, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity

I'm using Web API and Asp.net Identity to perform user related Operations.
Trying to Reset the Password With token Generated from GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync method,
but I'm getting the error "Invalid Token" 
Note:
Using Kubernetes and having Multiple Instances(pods) of the application, I'm facing this error. However, when running locally, it works fine.

```
private static UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

public async Task<IActionResult> ForgotPassword(string email)
{
  var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
  var resetToken = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
  result = await SendForgotPasswordLinkEmail(email, resetToken);
  if (result)
    return Ok(result);
  else
    return BadRequest(result);
}
public async Task<IActionResult> ResetPassword(model)//model contains all neccessary values
{
  var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
  var check =await_userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user,model.ResetPasswordToken,model.Password);               
}
```

Comment: SECURITY - Forgotten password should always `return Ok()`. There should be no information transmitted back to the client, either in the response or the time the response takes to come back to the client, that could indicate the validity of the email address.

Comment: is this classing asp.net or core? the solution in any case i think is to centralize the encryption key storage

Comment: I meant to ask if this is classic or .net core

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro how would you centralize the key storage? Is there any recomended way to do that or to configure Identity to do so?

Comment: @Machado you can use a database to store the keys, you can use a file or even put them behind an api.... it is up to you.. it is very simple. I do it all the time when creating apps that will run in a loadbalancer

Comment: Yeah @JonathanAlfaro, I really would like to follow that path and I did end up doing that, with a Redis DB. I wish I found the Microsoft docs that talk about how to do that earlier. Here's the docs I used for reference in case anyone needs it as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks @Machado for your reference: Here's a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

problem is each instance has its own memory where the data are stored.
and we can't ensure that the same instance created the reset token will handle the change password because of that it let to mismatches

to solve this issue we need to create a store point where each instance can share the data for communication which prevent data mismatch more info about this is in the link

**another workaround:**
you can create your own salt key for the user and with that, you can confirm the user to reset password and resetting can be done by using

- Remove Password Method
- Add Password Method

**(Note: vulnerability inversely proportional to your salt key encryption)**